# Virtual Network Interface

Tags: virtualization

I have a question about setting up a customized network over virtual machines.
I just have access to one cloud provider that gives me ability to load multiple virtual machines. Each user may have his own VMs that will be loaded during a time or at the same time.
Each VM has two network interfaces. One of them is public interface that allow user to ssh or RDP to this machine and one another is a private network with ip range of 10.10.x.x that is used for internal communication between cloud managed and these machines. I just wanted to define a new network among these machines with ip range of 192.168.x.x . in fact I want VMs use their own IPs  and also add my new IP address to these machines. What options do I have?
Consider that, each time I make some VMs they will acquire new IP addresses and for each user I wanted to have exactly one group of VMs with predefined IP addresses.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: please explain exactly what you want to know from us.

Comment: I want to make a private network between these virtual machines like following image : http://i44.tinypic.com/14tjl4.jpg , in fact i want to make red lines

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud provider would not provide for a separate "private" network for all of your machines, you have no other chance but to tunnel through a VPN - in a typical setup it also would create a new "virtual" VPN subnet and VPN interfaces would receive addresses from the virtual subnet's address pool.

Comment: how can I make VPN automatically? when I make some virtual machines they will have new IP addresses and I need to find those IP addresses in someway and make a VPN between these machines.

Comment: @Mani I don't quite understand what you mean by "automatically". Of course VPNs need to be set up. There can be automation methods for deployment depending on your operating system and the VPN solution chosen.

Comment: I know, the problem here is that I want to set up some images with the network configuration between them(probably one vpn) and next time I want to see that I have this network between images. I don't want to do this manually everytime.